# Problem in building Aquasim module in NS3

Tags: c++, networking, ns-3

I am getting the following error while building aquasim

```
    In file included from ./ns3/object-base.h:23:0,
                 from ./ns3/object.h:29,
                 from ./ns3/energy-source.h:30,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-energy-model.cc:21:


    ./ns3/type-id.h: In instantiation of ‘static ns3::ObjectBase*     ns3::TypeId::AddConstructor()::Maker::Create() [with T = ns3::AquaSimEnergyModel]’:
    ./ns3/type-id.h:659:3:   required from ‘ns3::TypeId ns3::TypeId::AddConstructor() [with T = ns3::AquaSimEnergyModel]’
    ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-energy-model.cc:42:42:   required from here
    ./ns3/type-id.h:656:27: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type   ‘ns3::AquaSimEnergyModel’


       ObjectBase * base = new T ();
                           ^~~~~~~~
    In file included from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-energy-model.cc:26:0:
../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-energy-model.h:45:7: note:   because the following virtual    functions are pure within ‘ns3::AquaSimEnergyModel’:
    class AquaSimEnergyModel : public DeviceEnergyModel
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from ./ns3/device-energy-model-container.h:26:0,
                 from ./ns3/energy-source.h:34,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-energy-model.cc:21:

    ./ns3/device-energy-model.h:106:16: note:   virtual void   ns3::DeviceEnergyModel::HandleEnergyChanged()

     virtual void HandleEnergyChanged (void) = 0;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Waf: Leaving directory `/home/udit/ns-allinone-3.30.1/ns-3.30.1/build'
    Build failed
    -> task in 'ns3-aqua-sim-ng' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more   information)
```

Comment: Based on the GitHub page of Aquasim, it can only be used with NS 3.24, 3.26, and 3.27. I can see you are using NS 3.30. So, in my opinion, you should try with the aforementioned versions as suggested by the original source. Another issue might arise, as they have not suggested the Ubuntu version. Because every Ubuntu comes with a gcc/g++ version. gcc/g++ version might also create issues.

Answer (score -1):

try to build ns3 according to this, https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_build_old_versions_of_ns-3_on_newer_compilers

or please provide more details of your NS3 version and GCC compiler.